# Linked lists insertion (core dumped)

Tags: c++, linked-list, coredump

my header and implimentation file

```
#ifndef VIKTOR_H_
#define VIKTOR_H_

#include <iostream>

template <class DataType>
class viktor {

private:
    template <class NodeType>
    struct Node {

        NodeType data;
        Node<NodeType> * next;

    };

    Node<DataType> * backPtr;
    int length;

public:

    viktor();
    ~viktor();

    DataType &operator [] (int) const;

    void push(const DataType &);

    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &strm, const 
viktor<DataType> &A){

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {

            strm << A[i] << " " << std::flush;
        }

        strm << std::endl;

        return strm;
    }
};
template <class DataType>
viktor<DataType>::viktor() {

backPtr = nullptr;

length = 0;
}
template <class DataType>
viktor<DataType>::~viktor() {

if ( length == 0 ) return;

Node<DataType>* previousPtr = backPtr;
Node<DataType>* nextPtr = backPtr->next;

while( nextPtr != backPtr )
{

    nextPtr = nextPtr->next;

    previousPtr->next = nullptr;
    delete previousPtr;
    length--;

}

backPtr->next = nullptr;
delete backPtr;
}
template <class DataType>
void viktor<DataType>::push(const DataType &item) {

Node<DataType>* newNode = new Node<DataType>;

newNode->data = item;

std::cout << "data: " << newNode->data << std::endl;

if(length != 0) {

    newNode->next = backPtr->next;
    backPtr->next = newNode;
}
else {

    newNode->next = newNode;
}

backPtr = newNode;

length += 1;
//std::cout << "Finished pushing..." << std::endl;
}
template <class DataType>
DataType &viktor<DataType>::operator [] (int i) const {

Node<DataType>* conductor = backPtr;

if (i > length) {

    throw "Item is inaccessible";
}
for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {

        conductor = conductor->next;
}

return conductor->data;
}

#endif //VIKTOR_H_
```

i am having problems with this function

```
template <class DataType>
void viktor<DataType>::push(const DataType &item) {

Node<DataType>* newNode = new Node<DataType>;

newNode->data = item;

std::cout << "data: " << newNode->data << std::endl;

if(length != 0) {

    newNode->next = backPtr->next;
    backPtr->next = newNode;
}
else {

    newNode->next = newNode;
}

backPtr = newNode;

length += 1;
//std::cout << "Finished pushing..." << std::endl;
}
```

i am using this test driver

```
int main() {

viktor<int> blah;

blah.push(2);

std::cout << blah << std::endl;
}
```

now it works if i only push once but if i do

```
blah.push(1);
blah.push(2);
```

it runs and prints all of the data that i want but at the end of the program it dumps my core (i can provide the specific error if you want but it's just a memory map and then `aborted (core dumped)`)

Comment: First please read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Then learn how to use [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) as well as how to use an actual debugger to catch crashes "in action". When you catch the crash in a debugger, you can learn its location in your code, and also examine values of all involved variables.

Comment: i have gone through all the steps, i have used the debugger, thank you but i really just need someone more experience to take a look at it :)

Comment: Then can you tell us *where* the crash happens? And what the values of all involved variables were?

Comment: Oh and a few hints: If the crash happens when the program ends, it's likely a problem in cleanup-code (like a destructor). And talking about destructors, you have a loop where you `delete previousPtr` but you never reassign `previousPtr` to points anywhere else... If you stepped through your code in a debugger that last thing would have been *very* obvious.

Comment: the crash is at the end of the program and it outputs data: 1 data: 2 1 2 then goes into a memory map and then `aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: ah ok so its probably the deconstructor then

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it! thanks Some programmer dude! so the problem was my deconstructor, what i did was changed `previousPtr->next = nullptr;` to `previousPtr = previousPtr->next;`

Comment: It is called a "destructor", not "deconstructor".